# Unable to execute Nunit 3 .Net Core tests on VSTS with Test Plan option

Tags: .net, nunit, azure-devops

My story is that I'm trying to setup VSTS build step to run couple of NUnit test that are attached to test plan on .Net Core 2.0. And there absolutely no info how to do it correctly (though I managed to run tests but without the test plan which I need). I'm trying different solutions and combinations (I managed to get it working but on .net full framework, using infor from this post [Error while executing Run Functional Test task in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622707/error-while-executing-run-functional-test-task-in-vsts)). I have read that one way to fix for .Net core it is to use vstest.console.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe but I receive this weird error now.

"Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.FilterExpressionWrapper' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.":

Comment: What's the result if you call vstest.console.exe to run test manually on your local machine? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starian-chen-msft I can execute Nunit based .NetCore 2.0 tests using VSTS via assembly filter. But I have no luck if I use Manual test Plan filter option in VSTS Test Assembly step since it uses combination of tcm.exe and DTA.exe to perfom test discovery. 
https://www.screencast.com/t/VGvY5nUd

Comment: What's the detail setting of assembly filter? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT I'm using Test plan not the TestAssemblies option for 'Select tests using' dropdown. I did manage to get it working with 'TestAssemblies' option but it is impossible currently with 'Test plan'

Comment: I would like to know the other setting of test task, also can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starian-chen-msft Here is some more info on the topic https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6287. It has steps to reproduce. If it will be not enough I can provide you with more details

Comment: I can reproduce this issue too, I think as acesiddhu said that "we don't support associating .net core test and nunit test with a test case."

Answer (score 0):

I found this recipe to use the *Visual Studio Test* Task against .Net Core 2 (forgot the source).

1. Set `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform` as the *Specific Location* for the Test Platform
2. `/Framework:FrameworkCore10` for *Other console options*

[image: snap of Execution options]

Comment: did you manage to execute the test based on manual test plan? I trying to execute based on you answer and still receive System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.FilterExpressionWrapper' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Here is my config https://www.screencast.com/t/VGvY5nUd

Comment: Also noticed a new warning during test execution: Other console options is not supported when using the multi-agent phase setting. This option will be ignored

Comment: I can't drill down on this right now, but it sounds like you need some Visual Studio piece that is still unsupported in the TPv2. Your best chance is to interact on GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues) with your issue.

Comment: I receive such info from one of the threads in Microsofts GitHub
   1. we don't support associating .net core test and nunit test with a test case.
   2. for running .net core test you need to use .net core task. running netcore test via vstest task is not supported currently
    3. also we should not copy nunit adapter to extension folder. that folder is meant for out of the box adapters that ship as part of VS

I they don't support it how it works with Nunit on Full framework